# How has StackExchange helped you, as opposed to a search engine?

Tags: discussion

In place of Google, StackExchange offers me a place to get helpful (useful) information from real people without having to sift through the world wide web for my morsel of information. I'm curious in knowing, **how much has StackExchange (the network of sites) helped you as opposed to other sites you find in a search engine?**

On a side note, Community based networks are relatively new. Information is now globally accessible across a wide-base of community sites that you can depend on 86% of the time for accurate information. Unlike Google, where you'll have to spend an hour or 2 to verify a morsel of information you may find on a particular site (years ago). Now however, community sites are starting to boost the Search Engine's ability to offer relevant information.

Comment: How does finding an answer in an SE post through Google count?

Comment: Technically it's a link to a community site, so exclude those found in search results. Of course you can reference the SE post as if you came their from SE. I'm saying opposed to other content in search engines like links to actual website pages (forums, blogs that are not editable by everyone (or could be)) and knowledge-bases.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's just about replaced it. I have to keep telling myself to Google first, just to be sure that it's not something blatantly obvious so that I'm not wasting everyone's time, and even then I still look for results from SE. My questions get answered here faster than I can dig through Google to find them, most of the time.

The best part is that every time a question is asked and an answer is given, specific instructions to specific questions are posted up in an easy-to-follow format, thus making it easier for search engines to do their job and offer relevant results.

Comment: Yes, So you have experienced this. I find searching for a problem on Google with a SE link usually solves my problem. Unless its such an obscure variation of the problem. Then I'm asking it on a SE site!